# How to extract and download web scrape image using BeautifulSoup Selenium Python?

Tags: beautifulsoup

the images I am trying to get are inside an  and I want the High resolution images.

I have found this code here but it doesn't seem to work.

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from selenium import webdriver

from time import sleep

from cookie_accepter3 import load_and_accept_cookies

driver = webdriver.Safari()

def getdata(url):

```
r = requests.get(url) 

return r.text
```

URL = 'https://www.duelingbook.com/deck?id=13690926

htmldata = getdata("https://www.duelingbook.com/deck?id=13690926")

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('img'):

```
print(item['src'])
```

Any help , appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Getting high res images really depends on the source. Does the source provide you with high res? Do they allow resolution parameters to be passed?

Unless you're using something like OpenCV or related tech, you may not be able to upscale the images dimensions into high res.

Comment: What link should i wroge in URL? What link writer in HTML data ?

Comment: Can you try looking at their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

I think your code seems fine really. It may be that the source doesn't provide you with high-res images

Comment: What link should i wroge in URL? What link writer in HTML data ?